# How to get pixel matrix of recognized objects when classifying a image using Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-recognition

I want to get pixel matrix of objects within a image when the image is classified by Tensorflow (classify_image.py).

In other words, the recognized objects must be segmented first.
E.g. there is a computer in the picture, i want to get all pixels which belong to the computer.

But till now i cannot find a sample from Tensorflow's tutorial.

The only things i can get is the recognition results through sample code of Tensorflow.

e.g.

```
softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('softmax:0')
predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,
                       {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
predictions = np.squeeze(predictions)

# Creates node ID --> English string lookup.
node_lookup = NodeLookup()

top_k = predictions.argsort()[-FLAGS.num_top_predictions:][::-1]
for node_id in top_k:
  human_string = node_lookup.id_to_string(node_id)
  score = predictions[node_id]
  print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

Does someone have an idea?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links to models for image segmentation using TensorFlow :

- [TensorBox](https://github.com/Russell91/TensorBox)
- [DeConvNet](https://github.com/fabianbormann/Tensorflow-DeconvNet-Segmentation)
- [Segmentation Toolkit](https://github.com/MarvinTeichmann/Tensorflow-Segmentation-Toolkit)